# Android CollapsingToolbarLayout Title padding while collapsed

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-support-library

I'm trying to use `app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance` for my title while collaping toolbar layout is collapsed and showing toolbar only.
this is my problem:

[image] [image]

I have used `app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance` and this is the style:

```
<style name="about_title">
    <item name="android:paddingRight">100dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginRight">10dp</item>
</style>
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Isn't it because of your android:layout_marginRight set to 10dp? Can you add the same dp for android:layout_marginEnd and paddingEnd too?

Comment: yes still nothing